# Problems with SignalR when running karma in Angular app

Tags: angular, signalr, karma-jasmine

I have an issue when trying to setup karma in a angular project. I get an error when running ng test. It's my first time working with angular and karma. I already checked other stackoverflow posts but can't find anyone with a similar error.

Anyone who recognizes the error or has any idea what I did wrong?

*"Error during loading: Uncaught Error: jQuery was not found. Please ensure jQuery is referenced before the SignalR client JavaScript file. in http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/vendor.js line 4831"*

**Karma.conf.js:**

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    webpack: {
      node: {
        fs: 'empty',
        child_process: 'empty',
        readline: 'empty'
      }
    },
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      jasmine: {
        // you can add configuration options for Jasmine here
        // the possible options are listed at https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Configuration.html
        // for example, you can disable the random execution with `random: false`
        // or set a specific seed with `seed: 4321`
      },
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    jasmineHtmlReporter: {
      suppressAll: true // removes the duplicated traces
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/myProject'),
      subdir: '.',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html' },
        { type: 'text-summary' }
      ]
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "myProject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/localize": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.4",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^15.4.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^15.4.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^15.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^15.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^15.4.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.5",
    "sass": "^1.60.0",
    "signalr": "^2.4.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.1",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.45",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^4.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^15.2.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.5"
  }
}
```

```
/// <reference path="..\..\SignalR.Client.JS\Scripts\jquery-1.6.4.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.signalR.js" />
(function($, window, signalrPath) {
```

Please let me know if you need any information.

Comment: Can you add picture of Angular.json file ?